# Programatically index keys or attributes with App Engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I would put a  Entity like this:

```
Key entityKey = _ds.put(e); // Using DatastoreService
```

Where e is a `Entity` type, how can I *programatically* specify that a certain property in the Entity should be indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `entity.setProperty("propertyName", "value")`, it will be indexed.

If you use `entity.setUnindexedProperty("propertyName", "value")`, it will not be indexed.